# Rename file in jar

Tags: java, jar, minecraft

I have a 'jar file' that has a file in it named 'extension.yml'. I want to rename this file to 'plugin.yml'. Normally, I would decompile, change the file name, and recompile. But here, I can't do this because there are literally hundreds of dependencies, and decompiling one by one will take a lots of time.

Is there a more convenient way to rename just this file inside jar without decompiling it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just uppack the jar. It is just a zip-file.
Therefore, you should simply rename/remove the file within the zip.
Since yml looks like a simple config file (which is simple text), you don't need to compile anything. Unless you also want to rename any references to the yml in some `.class` files.

Comment: Thanks this helped!

Comment: you can also use `jar` (`jar.exe`) that is part of JDK (e.g. for writing a shell script)

Answer (score 0):

Change the .jar extension of the jar file to .zip extension -> Extract the zip file using 7zip or anything else -> Locate the.file in the extracted zip and change the name -,> Again convert the directory as zip file -> Change the extension to jar from zip. You will get back the jar file

Answer (score 0):

jar files are mostly zip files (there are some peculiar rules), but any zip tool that can rename files inside a zip can be used here. This isn't easy either, but for example `zipnote` should be able to. See [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/491873/is-it-possible-to-rename-files-in-a-zip-archive-before-extracting).